# Regex that allows blank or specific sequence

Tags: regex

I have a regex validator that validate comma seperated number sequences :-

> 1,1234,123,12,125

Here is the regex:-

```
^([0-9]+,|){1,4}\d+(,\d+|)$
```

I need the regular expression to only validate where there is a sequence to check. If no sequence is entered, it should also pass.

How do i amend the pattern to allow null entries?

Comment: You don't need `regex` you can simply check `value == ''`

Comment: Your regex has limitations, would more think of something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/xF5cQ4/1) `^\d*(?:,\d+){0,5}$` which should match pretty much the same plus nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?:\d+(?:,\d+)*)?$
```

Try this.This will accept null values.

Comment: I will, in 5 minutes,when allowed.